# Macro Button with Arguments on Mac Excel 2015

Tags: excel, macos, vba

I have created an Excel spreadsheet with buttons that run macros and call arguments. For example, if the macro is called "PrintNumber" and it takes one String argument, I type 'PrintNumber "five"' after right-clicking "Assign Macro."

This works fine on Mac Excel 2011, Windows Excel 2015, and Windows Excel 2016. However, it is not working on Mac Excel 2015. Does anybody know why and how I can work around this?

Comment: "not working" looks like what exactly ?

Comment: "Cannot run the macro "Spreadsheet.xlsm'!PrintNumber "five"'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

Comment: Sometimes it says "The macro [macro name] cannot be found."

Comment: Sorry - I don't have a Mac to test on.